# C, Malformed int to char[] after strcat

Tags: c

When printing a char[] that has the value of an int concat'ed into it, the int is not correct. However the printf of `str` after the `sprintf` outputs the correct value.

I'm using this code:

```
  int i;
  for( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        char str[20];
        sprintf(str, "%i", i);
        char in[50] = "INSERT INTO `Test` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('1', '";
        strcat(in, str);
        strcat(in, "')");
        printf("%s", in);
   }
```

Output: `INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('1', 'A&?0')`

Comment: p.s if anyone can suggest a cleaner or more efficient way of building strings, please do say :)

Comment: `int size = snprintf(NULL, "INSERT INTO 'Test' ('Col1', 'Col2') VALUES ('1', '%d')", i);` will give you the minimum size of your array.

Comment: BTW if it's just to printf in the end, as in your code extract, just forget str, in and the 2 strcat, just use printf in one line of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` is too small as the string literal is `50` characters, meaning the `strcat()` afterwards are writing beyond the end of the buffer causing undefined behaviour, in this case causing corruption (in fact the string literal is `50 + 1` due to the implicit null terminator appended to string literals). To correct increase the size of the buffer and use [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to prevent buffer overrun and to perform the string construction in a single operation. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    char str[128];

    const int result =
        snprintf(str,
                 sizeof(str),
                 "INSERT INTO `Test` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('1', '%i')",
                 i);

    if (-1 == result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create 'INSERT' statement\n.");
    }
    else if (result >= sizeof(str))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create 'INSERT' statement: truncated\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[%s]\n", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: good spot :) when i use `snprintf` i get segmentation fault, but using `sprintf` executes correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You declare this:

```
char in[50] = "INSERT INTO `Test` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('1', '";
```

but

```
sizeof "INSERT INTO `Test` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('1', '"
```

is 51 characters.

Which means that there is not enough room for the null terminator in your original `in` array, so `in` is not a string so can you cannot concatenate anything to it and as `hmdj` wrote even if it was a string there would be no room left to concatenate anything as it is full.